# Ocultar un botón si un campo viene vacio: en MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un formulario **facturación** donde ingreso varios datos, entre ellos, puedo subir un archivo en **pdf** este último no es un campo obligatorio, por tal motivo cuando guardo mi formulario, no voy a tener un archivo para visualizar.

> Lo que busco: que si el campo **Archivo** llega vacío, que no se muestre el botón de **visualizar** en el index.

Las siguientes son las imágenes de como funciona.

[image: Acá subo (o no) la imagen]

[image: En la segunda imagen se ve que el campo **Archivo** en uno está lleno y en el otro vacio]

[image: Error si se da clic en >ver, por no tener imagen]

Answer (score 2):

Esto lo hice un proyecto hace unos años. Espero el ejemplo te sirva.

A medida que vas llenando la grilla, verificás si tiene archivo. En este caso `TieneArchivo` es un booleano.

```
 @foreach (var Ensayo in Model)
     {    
      <li>
         @Html.HiddenFor(x => Ensayo.IDEnsayo)
         @Html.CheckBox("Checkbox",false)
         @Html.DisplayFor(x => Ensayo.Fecha, "ShortDateTime") 
         @if (Ensayo.TieneArchivo)
                {
                 @Html.ActionLink("PDF", "Get", "Archivos", new { IDEnsayo = Ensayo.IDEnsayo }, new { @class = "pdf-icon-l", title="Abrir archivo PDF" })
                }
      </li>                              
 }
```

**Nota:** Es con renderizado **razor**.

Este es el controlador:

```
public ActionResult Get(int IDEnsayo)
    { 

        var Ensayo = new Ensayo {IDEnsayo = IDEnsayo };
        Ensayo.LoadArchivo(); /*Trae el el archivo desde la base de datos*/
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Ensayo.Archivo.Contenido, 0, 0, true, true);
        Response.ContentType = Ensayo.Archivo.Tipo;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Ensayo.Archivo.Nombre);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, Ensayo.Archivo.Tipo);

    }
```

En la aplicación se ve así:

Fijate que la fecha que no tiene archivo, no muesta nada, en cambio si lo tiene, muestra un ícono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola, en tu controlador para TieneArchivo, que código tienes? no lo tengo muy claro.

Comment: En el controlador tengo una acción específica para el archivo. Solo la muestro si el objeto tiene un archivo asociado.

Comment: Como puede contactarte, para un par de preguntas por interno Sr, Pablo.

Comment: Lo que te convendría hacer es: Si las preguntas tienen que ver con lo que escribí, preguntá por acá. Si tienen que ver con algun tema relacionado inderectamente, planteala en el sitio y la respondo por acá. Consultas particulares no hago.